# setting automatic daily backup between Linux machine and a windows ftp server

Tags: linux, backup, ftp

I was given space on a Windows server machine for the purpose of backup. I can connect to this server using filezilla, but through command where I get an error:

```
534 Policy requires SSL.
```

I want to set a daily backup between my machine and the ftp server. I tried using duplicity, but I get the same error. How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I want to make this clear. I'm not searching to establish a secure connection with filezilla, I want to be able to run a script that copies files to this ftp server, or better, yet, run a back program that can do that.

I tried to mount the remote server using `curlftpfs` but I get:

> > curlftpfs -k -o ssl,utf8 ftp://
> >     Error connecting to ftp: SSL: certificate subject name () does not match target host name

which is weird to me since I provide the ip address and not the url (goes to show how little I understand in web security).

Answer (score 1):

It seems your FTP server mandate's secure connections.
Look into this:
https://support.managed.com/kb/a1985/ftp-error-could-not-connect-to-server-534-policy-requires-ssl.aspx

Comment: Yes, the question is how do I achieve this secure connection with a backup tool?

Comment: Does it work if you use sftp instead?About the certificate name error, the digital certificate is provided to the server with a hostname.
When you connect, it tries to compare the hostname you entered to the hostname in the digital certificate.
If they match, that means you are connecting to the correct server. If they don't match you get a warning about it because you may be connecting to a different server (maybe you got redirected to a different server maliciously and you don't trust sending your credentials to that server because they may got stolen. that's why you receive the warning).

Comment: If you connect using the IP address then you will surely get a warning message because the IP address won't match the hostname with the digital certificate. The same concept applies to TLS/SSL certificate with HTTPS websites. If you try to connect to a trusted website (say https;//superuser.com) user the IP address rather than the hostname, you'll get a warning. try it. (try to connect to google search with its IP, say https://216.58.198.3. you will probably get a warning by your browser)
It is up to the application to decide if you can proceed after the warning or you stop at this point.